# Mutt Outlook messages distorted

Tags: mutt

I started using Mutt and the only issue I am having is that when I receive an email from an Outlook account, I get a bunch of headers and all of the HTML. It is very hard to read. what I want to do is be able to read these properly and also have the ability to send my email as HTML. What setup do I have to have in order for this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To view HTML mail in `mutt`:

Add the following to your `~/.muttrc`:

```
# convert text/html to text/plain using the "copiousoutput" entry
# for text/html from ~/.mailcap

auto_view text/html

# Optionally prefer text/plain to text/html
# Doing this means that you will need to manually view text/html attachments
# in messages that are multipart/alternative with both text/plain and
# text/html attachments.

alternative_order text/plain text/html
```

And one of these two lines to `~/.mailcap`:

```
text/html; /usr/bin/links -html-numbered-links 1 -dump '%s'; copiousoutput; description=HTML Text; nametemplate=%s.html

text/html; /usr/bin/lynx -dump -force_html '%s'; copiousoutput; description=HTML Text; nametemplate=%s.html
```

(you could also use `w3m` or `text2html` or some other program to convert HTML to plain text, but you will have to read the man pages for them to find the appropriate command line options)

`mutt` will use the command specified in `~/.mailcap` to convert the text/html attachment to text/plain and display it in the `mutt` viewer.

## To send HTML mail from `mutt`:

I have no idea because I have self-respect and have never wanted to perpetrate such an abomination.

Comment: Good advice in regards to sending HTML mail from mutt. I will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: of course, i was only half-serious about that bit :)